Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Shrink to fit (text) - disable if selection is not range
This is a follow-up question to this one:
Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Shrink to fit (text) - exclude charts from selection
Using If not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Exit Sub, the button now knows to only work, if the selection is a range. In other words: If the selection is anything else than a range, e.g. a chart, the procedure is stopped.
How do you enable/disable the button to mirror this behavior and change its state depending on the selection?

Selection = range > enabled
Selection = not range > disabled

Will it need the property getEnabled?
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadRibbon">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                  
        <group id="Group6" label="Alignment">
          <toggleButton id="ToggleButton1" 
                        label="Shrink to fit" 
                        imageMso="AsianLayoutCharacterScaling" 
                        size="large"
                        getPressed="ToggleButton1_Startup" 
                        onAction="ToggleButton1_OnAction"/>       
        </group>           
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Standard Module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub

' ToggleButton 1 Startup
Sub ToggleButton1_Startup( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef returnedVal)
   If not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Exit Sub
   returnedVal = (Selection.ShrinkToFit = True)
End Sub

' ToggleButton 1 Click
Sub ToggleButton1_OnAction( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef pressed As Boolean)
   If not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Exit Sub
   Select Case pressed
      Case True
            Selection.ShrinkToFit = True
      Case False
            Selection.ShrinkToFit = False
   End Select
End Sub


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub



The most challenging part is that when the user selects non-Range object (eg. a chart or shape), it doesn't trigger the Sheet event code. Therefore, there's no way to refresh the Ribbon with RibUI.InvalidateControl.
